# How to properly configure linkedDocuments (pushpin) on create issue request

Tags: autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative

I have an app which I want to implement Issues creation with it's position in ACCs projects, I know that the pushpin feature's not avaliable in ACC, but I'm tryng to test it anyway using the [bim360 docs](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/pushpins/create-pushpin-v2/)

The problem is that I'm already creating the issues and it comes with the position, and in my app, the 3d markup sprite is working, but in ACC docs viewer this issues doesn't appear, they're being shown in the list on the left, but not in the viewer, and I want it to show in both my viewer and ACC viewer.

My BODY resquest code:

```
{
      title: title,
      issueSubtypeId: issueSubtypeId,
      status: status,
      linkedDocuments: [
        {
          urn: urn,
          createdAtVersion: parseInt(result[1], 10),
          type: "TwoDVectorPushpin",
          details: {
            position: position,
            objectId: object_id,
            viewable: {
              id: viewer1.model.getDocumentNode().data.guid,
              name: viewer1.model.getDocumentNode().data.name,
              viewableId: viewer1.model.getDocumentNode().data.viewableID,
              is3D: true,
            },
            viewerState: state,
          },
        },
      ],
    }
```

Where:

`const state = viewer1.viewerState.getState();`

`const object_id = e.clickInfo.dbId;` and `"e"` is a `DataVizCore.MOUSE_CLICK` event

I know that the only thing that's missing in `linkedDocuments.details` is `externalId` which I don't know where to find it, but I don't think this is the solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As per [Issues API limitation](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/overview/field-guide/issues/#limitations) statement:

> You cannot add issues to sheets, models, or files (pushpins). You can retrieve issues that are associated with files, however, we do not currently support retrieving issues that are associated with sheets in the ACC Build Sheet tool.

What you can do is try comparing with the response you get from the API through the steps below:

1. Create an Issue through ACC Viewer UI
2. Use [GET Issue](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/reference/http/issues-issues-GET/) endpoint to retrieve this issue's parameters
3. Use [POST Issue](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/reference/http/issues-issues-POST/) to create issues through API

Since it's not officially supported, though, we advise to wait for official API support. Once it's available, we'll cover the steps in docs.

Sorry for not having a solution for this.